# .htaccess rewrite links and src

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently have an imported a site from a server which has its resources something like this:

```
<img src="/dir/bunch_of_diff_stuff">
<script src="/dir/bunch_of_diff_stuff">
<link href="/dir/bunch_of_diff_stuff">
```

Basically, I access this site on my local environment like this in the browser:

```
localhost/~username/folder/project-1/html/
```

However, since the resources are written with the "/" directory prefix, it's loaded as:

```
localhost/dir/bunch_of_diff_stuff
```

What should I write in my **.htaccess** so the resources will be loaded as:

```
localhost/~username/dir/project-1/html/dir/bunch_of_diff_stuff
```

Comment: I personally would just set `DocumentRoot` in the webserver to the directory `~username/folder/project-1/html/`

Comment: ^yes, but I have a lot of project sites in my `~username directory`. The `~username/folder/project-1/html/` is just another project

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(dir/.*)$ /~username/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located ? Inside `/~username/` or a level above?

Comment: I placed it where `localhost/~username` is located, which is `/Users/Username/Sites`

Comment: That's not right. I mentioned in my answer `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`. This is the path where `http://localhost` is pointed.

Comment: oohh.. my bad. I've not transferred it to the *System Level Web Root* which is at `/Library/WebServer/Documents`. Still no luck

Comment: That means you don't know what is `DocumentRoot` for `localhost`. You need to check your Apache config and check what is `DocumentRoot` set to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73513/discussion-between-anubhava-and-burnzz).